# Values of the function parameters are changing randomly (but they're not modified from the code)

Tags: c++

I have to implement an NBC (for finding clusters in the provided set of data) algorithm at my class project with a friend. We came across very strange issue. There are few helper functions, and the one with a problem is kNN (possibly kEN too) in the kNB.h file. After passing arguments to it from the main function of the program (for example k=3 and p=5), it goes to the kNN function and starts changing values of k and p randomly, even though function code is not supposed to do that anywhere as you can see below.

Also, while using debugging mode and going through this function step by step I noticed that it sometimes comes back before the first while which I think shouldn't happen. I guess it may be some trivial mistake, but I'm not very good at C++ (unfortunately we were ordered to use it). You can download entire Visual Studio 2013 solution from here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1561186/EDAMI.zip. So, does anyone have any idea why described situation is happening?

```
static vector<int> kNN(int k, int p, Dataset<V>* records)
{
int b = p, f = p;
bool backwardSearch, forwardSearch;
vector<int> tmp;
LengthMetric<V>* lengthMetric = records->getLengthMetric();

backwardSearch = PrecedingPoint(records, b);

forwardSearch = FollowingPoint(records, f);

int i = 0;

while (backwardSearch && forwardSearch && i < k)
{

    if (records->getRecord(p)->getLength() - records->getRecord(b)->getLength() < records->getRecord(f)->getLength() - records->getRecord(p)->getLength())
    {
        i++;
        tmp.push_back(b);
        backwardSearch = PrecedingPoint(records, b);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        tmp.push_back(f);
        forwardSearch = FollowingPoint(records, f);
    }
}

while (backwardSearch && i < k)
{

    i++;
    tmp.push_back(b);
    backwardSearch = PrecedingPoint(records, b);
}

while (forwardSearch && i < k)
{
    i++;
    tmp.push_back(f);
    forwardSearch = FollowingPoint(records, f);
}

return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like memory corruption. Try valgrind!

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio, put a data breakpoint on the address of the variables that are changing.  When the variable changes, the debugger will stop and you can inspect exactly why the variables change.

Comment: Data breakpoint didn't help. But I just found answer myself - solution configuration was set to Release. When I set it to Debug, everything started working as it should! Sorry for trouble and thanks for help. I was right that it was trivial :)

Comment: @revanmj hiding a problem is not the same as solving it.

Comment: @revanmj `Data breakpoint didn't help`  That must mean you didn't use it correctly.  A data breakpoint's sole purpose is to detect changes in variables.  Also, the problem is not solved -- all you did was change to a Debug build.  The problem is still there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is solved - changing to Debug build resulted in normal values of the function parameters. And I was talking about values shown by debugger all the time.

As for the Data breakpoint (my guess is that was because this Release/Debug build) was stopping at random lines of code that had nothing to do with parameters. It even stopped at cout outside of this function where no variable was changed. So Release/Debug build was the only issue.

Comment: @revanmj - Next time, please state that you are using the debugger to determine what the values of the variables are.  Also, it would be beneficial if you ran the program outside the debugger to see if it actually behaves correctly or not.  Even so, if you ran it in the debugger without stopping, you should have seen that the program behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at second constructor of your class Dataset

```
Dataset(vector<Record<V>*> rrecords,
        LengthMetric<V>* metric = new DumbLengthMetric<V>())
    : records(rrecords),
      lengthMetric(lengthMetric) { // <-------------------
```

`lengthMetric(lengthMetric)` does nothing. Changing it to `lengthMetric(metric)` I got some result on your project and no one variable was changed.

BTW, do not include in zip any stuff like folders `Debug`, `Release` and files `*.sdf`, `*.ncb`